# Outlook 2010 - button made of div with padding in table cell?

Tags: html-email, outlook-2010

I am trying to create a simple blue button within a table cell for an email with whitespace left and right. Nothing I am doing seems to be working (as you can see there is some bloat in there), I have a blue rectangle that is the correct width, but it will not add space top and bottom.

It looks fine in Gmail, but I am having the issues with Outlook 2010 specifically. Is there another way I can do this?

I would like the text centered (v+h) within the blue rectangle with padding top and bottom.

image attached of the 2 buttons side by side in 2 cells as viewed in outlook 2010

```
<tr>
<td>
    <center>
            <div height="25px" style="background-color:#1d70b7; padding:5px; width:60%; margin-bottom:20px; margin-right:20px; margin-left:20px; max-width:250px; line-height:25px; height:25px;" width="250px">
                <p style="line-height:25px;"><font color="#FFFFFF">DNB</font></p>
                </div>
        </center>
    </td>
    <td>
        <center>
            <div height="25px" style="background-color:#1d70b7; padding:5px; width:60%; margin-bottom:20px; margin-right:20px; margin-left:20px; max-width:250px; line-height:25px; height:25px;" width="250px">
                <p style="line-height:25px;"><font color="#FFFFFF">FNB</font></p>
            </div>
        </center>
</td>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Campaign Monitor made what they call their "bulletproof button maker"

it is here: [buttons.cm](https://buttons.cm/)

Now I often have call to add a bit of padding, but don't do it around the actual text or button, do it in a wrapping div:

```
<div style="padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 15px;>
    <some button code>
</div>
```

And the REASON we use the `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` is because SOME clients don't like CSS shorthand (better safe than sorry). I hope this helps.

Comment: Important to note that many of the same clients that have spotty box modal support also don't support the box modal `<div>`s very well. Safer to put this extra padding in `<tables>` and `<td>`s.

Answer (score 0):

[I answered a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42251659/734487). Long story short, buttons like this require more code than it would on the web / email clients with decent box model support. Extra spacing can be applied with `padding` (not `margin`) in the button's parent `<td>` tag.

```
<td align="center" style="padding: 15px 25px;">

    <!-- Button 1 : Begin -->
    <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" style="margin: auto; display: inline-block;">
        <tr>
            <td style="border-radius: 4px; background: #1d70b7; text-align: center;">
                <a href="http://www.google.com" style="background: #1d70b7; border: 5px; solid #1d70b7; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 13px; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff; display: block; border-radius: 4px;">
                    DNB
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- Button 1 : END -->
</td>

<td align="center" style="padding: 15px 25px;">
    <!-- Button 2 : Begin -->
    <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" style="margin: auto; display: inline-block;">
        <tr>
            <td style="border-radius: 4px; background: #1d70b7; text-align: center;">
                <a href="http://www.google.com" style="background: #1d70b7; border: 5px; solid #1d70b7; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 13px; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff; display: block; border-radius: 4px;">
                    FNB
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- Button 2 : END -->

</td>
```

---

This is one of a few similar techniques, [outlined on Litmus](https://litmus.com/blog/a-guide-to-bulletproof-buttons-in-email-design).

Answer (score 0):

i also had a similar problem to get my buttons work. a simple trick is to use border, because border is supported in all major mail clients. just add "border XXpx solid #color" to an a-tag to fake your padding. it works pretty good if you dont use borders far over 10px.